# Snort Log Question: What does the number at the end of snort.log mean?

Tags: snort

When a snort log filename is saved as snort.log.########. What does the number at the end represent? Is it randomly generated or is it the epoch date?

I have tried googling the answer to this but can't seem to find the answer. Can someone point out what the answer to this question is? If you know a legimate source that points out the answer then that would be bonus. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `snort.log.xxxxx` pcap format log files generated by snort are named using the epoch time of the first packet stored in the log.  This allows you to figure out which .log file a particular alert is in.  It is not random.

You can find a canonical reference [here](https://www.snort.org/faq/readme-unified2), which states:

> Note that by default, unified2 files have the create time (in Unix Epoch format) appended to each file when it is created.